# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when doing input_data.read_data_sets(..)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I pip installed Tensor Flow so I don't have tensorflow.examples so I got the souce input_data from GitHub. How ever I am getting the following error.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5gr8f26y'

This is my code.

```
import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/MNIST_data/", one_hot = True)
```

How do I solve this problem? There is another thread dealing with the exact same issue but that solution did not solve my problem. What should I do now? The input_data.py file is in my projects's directory. My project directory looks like this.

```
tensor_flow
          |
          tf.py
          input_data.py
```

I have tried and exhausted all means described in Stack Overflow. Please do not indicate duplicates.

> runfile('C:/Users/Nikhil/Desktop/Tensor Flow/tensf.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nikhil/Desktop/Tensor Flow')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Nikhil/Desktop/Tensor Flow/tensf.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nikhil/Desktop/Tensor Flow')
>
> File "C:\Users\Nikhil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nikhil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Nikhil/Desktop/Tensor Flow/tensf.py", line 26, in 
>       mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = True)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nikhil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py", line 211, in read_data_sets
>       SOURCE_URL + TRAIN_IMAGES)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nikhil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py", line 141, in maybe_download
>       urllib.request.urlretrieve(source_url, temp_file_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nikhil\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 198, in urlretrieve
>       tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpry0jmpiu'

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi That has no relation to this...

Comment: Is it the full stacktrace?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi No. The full stack trace just points to the mnist =  input_data.read_data_sets(...)

Comment: Extract those files on those two locations. Use 7zip. And then run your program.

Answer (score 1):

Ok do this:

Create a directory "MNIST_data" inside this location:

```
tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/
```

Copy and extract all of those downloaded files in that folder. This should solve your problem most probably.

I guess the error was that python is unable to open .gz files after downloading.

Comment: I am getting EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached. Even if I paste the extracted files there, it is still trying to download. What to do now?

Comment: One last and final thing you can try: Remove the extracted files from that folder and copy the zipped(.gz) files.

Comment: If it doesn't works then go to StackOverflow chatrooms and try to find someone who can resolve this issue. Or go to github and raise a ticket pointing to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the read_data_sets() function:

```
def read_data_sets(train_dir,
                   fake_data=False,
                   one_hot=False,
                   dtype=dtypes.float32,
                   reshape=True,
                   validation_size=5000):
```

Within this function this code is going to run:

```
TRAIN_IMAGES = 'train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TRAIN_LABELS = 'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
TEST_IMAGES = 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TEST_LABELS = 't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'

local_file = base.maybe_download(TRAIN_IMAGES, train_dir,
                                 SOURCE_URL + TRAIN_IMAGES)
with open(local_file, 'rb') as f:
  train_images = extract_images(f)
```

The `maybe_download()` is downloading the file on your windows temp directory and then trying to access it.

But it is unable to read that file due to restricted permission or some other reason.

So try working on file permissions I guess. I'm on linux or would have tested it for you.

You can do a workaround, download data manually to the current working folder. You can download from here:

```
TRAIN_IMAGES = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TRAIN_LABELS = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
TEST_IMAGES = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
TEST_LABELS = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
```

Comment: So I should just add this function to my code to make it work?

Comment: Did you try this as an argument: "MNIST_data/" removing the '/' in front?

Comment: It does not work. I will give you the full stack tarceback in my edit. Pls see edit.

Comment: Is there any other way to import the data set otherwise?

Comment: Ideally the data should be local. But since it could not find the data in the current working directory it's trying to download it.

Comment: I'll paste the download links in the answer too long to post here. Download manually and copy to the working folder.

Comment: What do you want me to download?

Comment: Let's move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129354/discussion-between-nikhil-raghavendra-and-mohammad-yusuf-ghazi).