# Tensorflow Error in Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, spyder

I am getting the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\RSRIKA~1.UOF\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpdl2lzd4j'

when I run the following lines of code:

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
```

The problem is in the second line `"mnist=...."` The first line doesn't produce any error in the iPython console, the second line produces the above error. I believe that this is the same error that was reported by another user here: [PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when doing input_data.read_data_sets(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866525/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-doing-input-data-read-data-se)

It doesn't look like that problem was resolved. Any help will be much appreciated. I am running the code on Spyder that comes with Anaconda. The answer at [Windows Tensorflow with Python unable to read mnist data due to permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076047/windows-tensorflow-with-python-unable-to-read-mnist-data-due-to-permissions) did not solve my problem. I reinstalled Anaconda and marked the box "for all users" but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076047/windows-tensorflow-with-python-unable-to-read-mnist-data-due-to-permissions

Comment: @MYGz Thanks, I tried that. I reinstalled Anaconda and marked the box "for all users" but it still gave the same error after that. In case this is helpful, the last part of the folder path in the error message changed from tmpd121zd4j to tmp42vw2cce. Every time I run the code, it changes this last part of the path in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem, this is what worked:

(i) Uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it for all users.

(ii) Open command prompt from windows as an administrator and upgrade pip (upgrading pip from the command prompt within spyder did not work, I got permission errors there).

(iii) InstallTensorFlow from the same command prompt using "pip install tensorflow". (The full pip command given on the TensorFlow download page did not work, I got permission errors using it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple workaround for this is that doesn't require reinstalling anything.

Download the [input_data.py file from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py), then add the following at the bottom of the file:

```
mnist = read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
```

After that, you can use Anaconda's python to run the `input_data.py` file:

```
$ python input_data.py
```

You only need to do this once. It will download the dataset into the `MNIST_data` folder without issuing the permissions error. After that, you can follow the TensorFlow tutorial and import the MNIST dataset as usual, and it should work correctly.

**Edit:** A possibly even-simpler workaround would be to put the following two lines of code into a `.py` file and run it using the python interpreter:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```